# Help me finding function which give this type of graph.

Tags: graphing-functions

Few days ago I was playing with graphing tool . For some function the graph came out to be like this-

[image]

When I zoomed it where it begins,it gave graph like this-

[image]

I was curious to know weather function is increasing just after $x=0$ or decreasing. But unfortunately I don’t remember what function I wrote that time. Can someone please help me becuase I keep thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

Try $x \sin(1/x)$.

For more generality, try

$x^a\sin(1/x^b)$
for different values of
$a$ and $b$.